# Firebase storage upload file and get getDownloadURL Error storage/object-not-found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rxjs, firebase-storage

I have a problem when I try to upload a file using uploadBytesResumable and want to retrieve the path of the file using getDownloadURL. However, sometimes I encounter an error:

"Firebase Storage: Object 'storatge_data/9d668c90-8381-4161-b9f1-d016f9b51837/files/xxx.m4a' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)"

I tried to fix the problem and checked the condition using:

```
if ((snapshot.bytesTransferred !== snapshot.totalBytes)) {
  return of(null)
}
```

But I still get the same error message sometimes.

this is my code

```
    const newUploadFiles = (files: File[], updateDocRef: DocumentReference<DocumentData>) => {
      const resUpload = [...uploadFilesImage]
      from(files).pipe(
        mergeMap((file, i: number) => {
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `storatge_data/${id}/files/${file.name}`)
            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file)
            return fromEventPattern((handler) =>
                uploadTask.on('state_changed', handler)
            ).pipe(
                mergeMap((snapshot: any) => {
                    const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                    resUpload[i].progress = parseInt(progress.toFixed(0))

                    setProressFiles((prev) => ([...prev, resUpload[i]]))

                    if ((snapshot.bytesTransferred !== snapshot.totalBytes)) {
                        return of(null)
                    }

                          return from(getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref)).pipe(
                        mergeMap(url => {
                            const type = classifyFile(file.name)
                            let setType: any = of(null)
                            if (type === 'music') {
                                setType = onDrop(file)
                            }
                            return from(setType).pipe(
                                map(fileDetail => ({
                                    file: url,
                                    type,
                                    fileDetail,
                                    hash: "",
                                    fileType: file.name.substring(file.name.lastIndexOf('.')),
                                    fileName: file.name
                                }))
                            )
                        })
                    )
                }),
                takeWhile(data => data === null, true),
                filter(each => each !== null)
            )
        }),
        toArray(),
        concatMap(data => {
            return from(updateDoc(updateDocRef, { files: data }))
        })
    ).subscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that all bytes have been received does not mean that writing the file has been completed yet, so you should not use it to determine that you can call `getDownloadURL`.

Instead, add a third handler to the `on('state_changed'` that is called when the upload has completed and the file has been finalized, as shown in this example from the Firebase documentation on [monitoring the status of an upload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress):

```
// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
  (snapshot) => {
    ...
  }, 
  (error) => {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
  }, 
  () => {
    // Handle successful uploads on complete
    // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...
    getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
      console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
    });
  }
);
```

---

Alternatively, it's worth noting that an [`UploadTask` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.uploadtask.md#uploadtask_interface) implement `then` and `catch`, so is also a `Promise` and you can `await` it to detect when the upload has finalized.

So:

```
await uploadTask;
const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
```

Or (without `await`):

```
uploadTask.then(() => {
  await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
    console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
  });
})
```